# Dynamically set class-type and class for OpenCSVReader Mapping

Tags: java, opencsv

I have three classes:

- parent class ParentClass
- child class ChildClass1 which inherits from ParentClass
- child class ChildClass2 which inherits from ParentClass

In ParentClass there is just one method which will be inherited by the child classes. Both child classes have different fields and getters and setters (getters and setters are not shown in the code example).
The child classes are representations of csv-files (OpenCSVReader). Although this is not related to my problem, just for the sake of completeness, the fields are annotated with constraints.

```
public class ParentClass {
    public boolean myMethod(){
    }
}

public class ChildClass1 extends ParentClass{
    @NotNull
    private String child1Field1

    @NotNull
    private String child1Field2
}

public class ChildClass2 extends ParentClass{
    @NotNull
    private String child2Field1

    @NotNull
    private String child2Field2
}
```

Furthermore I have a method in a totally different class. These are the first lines of the method using the OpenCSVReader (further in the method also CsvToBean etc. is used - not shown because it is not necessary for the problem itself):

```
private boolean compareFiles(File created, File template, ReportType reportType, Class<ChildClass1> reportClass) throws Exception{

    CSVReader readerTest = new CSVReader(new FileReader(created),';','\'');
    CSVReader readerTemplate = new CSVReader(new FileReader(template), ';', '\'');

    HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy<ChildClass1> strat = new HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy<>();
    strat.setType(reportClass);
```

What I try to achieve is to change the class type in the `HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy` and also the static class in 
`strat.setType` dynamically, so that ChildClass1 and 2 and also more ChildClasses can be used in this context. In other words I want to pass these parameters as arguments to the method `compareFiles()`.

I already tried generics but I it did not work so far. Probably generics are the solution but I'm not very familiar with this concept.

I hope I described the problem clear enough. If not, please do not hesitate to ask via a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [generic method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html), like this:

```
private <T extends ParentClass> boolean compareFiles(
    File created, 
    File template, 
    ReportType reportType, 
    Class<T> reportClass
) throws Exception {
   ...
   HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy<T> strat = new HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy<>();
   strat.setType(reportClass);
   ...
```

and invoke it like that:

```
compareFiles(created,template,reportType,ChildClass1.class);
...
compareFiles(created,template,reportType,ChildClass2.class);
```